# Sent mail from gmail not showing in cpanel sent mail

Tags: gmail, cpanel

I have set up my cpanel email address in Gmail under Check mail from other accounts (using POP3) and also under Send mail as (Mail is sent through: mail.mydomain.com Secured connection on port 587 using TLS)

Looking at Roundcube, I can see the received mails in there, but no sent mails - even though Gmail is sending via my domain server.

Is there a way to be able to view received AND sent mails that go through Gmail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately emails do not work like that. There is no security as to where an email can be sent from.

I can send an email to anyone in the world and make it look like it was sent from you, most SMTP servers don't verify this information (hence why Gmail can send email from your domain even without your credentials).

Also, although this should theoretically be possible since it's being sent through your domain's SMTP server, it would take a lot of data to be able to store *ALL* mail that passes through it as associate it with every account. That's why some web email clients only store sent items for around 30 days.

Good luck with finding a suitable solution. This is why many companies use an Exchange server since it provides complete tracking of sent and received emails and disallow the use of Gmail.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, although Gmail does require credentials to be able to send through mydomain.com server (user & pass).  Yes, I'm aware of exchange - but over the top for one user!